# What is causing the segfaults in this JNA wrapper for GMP

Tags: java, jna, gmp

So, the below java code segfaults during finalize.

```
public class Mpz_t extends com.sun.jna.Structure {
    public int _mp_alloc;
    public int _mp_size;
    public NativeLongByReference _mp_d;

    protected void initFieldOrder() {
        setFieldOrder(new String[] { "_mp_alloc", "_mp_size", "_mp_d" });
    }

    public Mpz_t() {
        super();
        initFieldOrder();
        allocateMemory();
        ensureAllocated();
    }

    public static class ByReference extends Mpz_t implements
        Structure.ByReference {

    }

    public static class ByValue extends Mpz_t implements
        Structure.ByValue {

    }

    @Override public void finalize() {
        Gmp.gmp().__gmpz_clear(this);
    }
}
```

`.__gmpz_clear()` destroys the struct on the C side as far as I'm aware. If I rip out that part, there is no segfault, but my code will leak memory. Anyone have ideas on this?

I might add that it does not reliably segfault. It will destruct maybe 20 of these structs properly before a problem occurs.

Comment: The problem is on the C side here.  If you haven't written the code, double check you are using the library correctly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm using it right. My other function bindings work great and I can calculate very well with it. In the GMP documentation it says:


    _/* Unless the program is about to exit, do ... */mpz_clear(integ);_

The __gmpz_clear function is the java binding for the code above, and it should only be being called when java/scala is done with the struct object.

Comment: As a matter of style, allocateMemory() and ensureAllocated() are superfluous.  You would only need to call ensureAllocated() (which in turn calls allocateMemory()) if you needed to perform some operations on said memory within the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer to my own problem, the solution is currently semi-hacky.

The problem is that the JNA call for `__gmpz_clear` is on a different thread than the garbage collector, and sometimes the garbage collector destroys the pointer data and other things before `__gmpz_clear` finishes executing. Adding a spinlock via `while(_mp_size > 0) ;` solves the problem entirely.

Comment: Technically, you're trying to ensure that the finalizer for the `Structure` auto-allocated memory runs *after* the finalizer for your `Structure` instance.  It's not that one finalizer runs on a different thread than the garbage collector.

Answer (score 0):

In order to ensure the cleanup runs in the proper order, you might consider overriding `Structure.autoAllocate(int size)` to return a customized `Memory` object which augments its existing finalizer to call `__gmpz_clear` prior to the existing finalizer which actually frees the allocated memory.

```
public class Mpz_t extends Structure {
    protected Memory autoAllocate(int size) {
        return new Memory(size) {
            protected void finalize() {
                GMP.gmp().__gmpz_clear(this);
                super.finalize();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This ensures that the memory is *always* "cleared" prior to being freed.

Comment: This doesn't resolve the issue unfortunately. My solution doesn't resolve it entirely (it still segfaults sometimes) but it does work most of the time.

Comment: When you use `Native.setProtected(true)`, what is the stack trace of the segfault?

Comment: Changing __gmpz_clear to pass by value rather than pass by reference fixes all the segfault problems, but memory still leaks for some reason. Ditto with my original solution.

Comment: re: pass by value - that's the sort of error that providing the original function declaration avoids in the first place.

Comment: The original function declaration is `mpz_clear(mpz_t)`, so you *must* pass the structure by value if you want reliable execution.  How have you determined that memory is leaking?

Comment: Despite the gc cleaning up the Mpz_t objects quickly, and despite an -Xmx256M argument to the JVM, my program will quickly swell to 900MB of ram used and start grinding the disk for more. If the java side was consuming the ram, my program would hit an Out of memory error around 300-370M of ram consumed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14071/discussion-between-technomage-and-markhammons)